# Can't drag files (js/css) from solution explorer into view

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Just installed update 1 of vs2013 and now I can't drag .js or .css files from the solution explorer into my html views anymore.

Before you could do this and vs automatically created a script tag or link tag to the file. I'm not sure if it has something to do with the update 1 but I really miss that now, is there a way to re-enable it?

Comment: If you managed to resolve this please can you enlighten the rest of us? Many thanks

Comment: Nope sorry, and I'm suprised there's so little attention to this. I guess not many people use it.

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem in VS 2015; resolved by (re-)enabling:

(Menubar) Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> General -> "Drag and drop text editing"

This not only affects the ability to drag and drop highlighted text (which is why I had turned it off in the first place), but also the ability to produce an automatically formatted link by dragging and dropping a file onto the editor window. There may be a way to separate the two, but I have not come across it.

The same option is present, by the way, in the same location, in VS 2012. However, I did not test the behavior of the option in that version.

Comment: Apparently VS 2017 defaults to off

Answer (score 1):

Try running as administrator, if you are not already.
I had this same problem. I tried @VictorSuarez's solution of adding the edited file's extension to the list of files to opened by the HTML Editor, but it did not immediately solve the problem. I then opened Visual Studio as an admin and was able to drag and drop links as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and this is how I fixed it...

Option 1:

Go to Tools > Options > Text Editor > File Extension

...and add the extension of the file you are editing. In the editor selection list choose HTML Editor if it is an html or quivalent code you are working on... or just select the kind of code you are writing. After that hit Ok, restart VS and it should work now...

Option 2:

Right click on the file and select open with HTML Editor, save as default, and that should work as well.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

**For vs2022** this should be fixed in: `Visual Studio 2022 version 17.3 Preview 3`. Accordingly with quote from "Fixed - Pending Release" [developer community issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/cant-drag-javascript-or-css-files-onto-an-html-pag/1526177) from Jul 13, 2022:

> A fix for this issue is now available in preview release. Try out the
> fix by installing the most recent preview from
> https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/preview/ .