# VS 2022, I can't drag and drop css file into a cshtml file

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-2022

I am working with VS2022 ASP.NET Core 6 MVC.

I tried to drag & drop one CSS file from explorer to a `.cshtml` file.
It should be made automatically like this code the same way-VS 2019

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

But prohibition icon shown when I am trying the drag & drop operation.

I started again VS 2022 with Administrator permissions, but it's still the same situation.

Any idea?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't drag files (js/css) from solution explorer into view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21649028/cant-drag-files-js-css-from-solution-explorer-into-view)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Drag & Drop is not yet supported in LSP-based editors. You can refer to this article：

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/cant-drag-javascript-or-css-files-onto-an-html-pag/1526177

Comment: VS upgrades never stop being frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

There is a work around suggested by Microsoft: Tools-->Options-->Text Editor-->HTML-->Advanced-->Use Legacy Razor Editor for Asp.NET (Yes) -->OK

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The work around that used was to add a temporary .html page to the project. Drag the controls to this page and cut and past them to the .chtml. It's just an extra step but it works.